# Meteor Facebook Native Login: r is not a function

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, meteor

I use this package: https://github.com/jsep/meteor-facebook-native-login
and the cordova-plugin: https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4

When I do Meteor.loginWithNativeFacebook({}), here is what I get:

```
I20161129-20:10:21.539(1)? 11-29 20:10:21.141  6596  6596 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(289)] "err", source: http://localhost:12120/3327d0d4e5e931942359c7d85bf5ea6bbbc9c525.js?meteor_js_resource=true (289)
I20161129-20:10:21.540(1)? 11-29 20:10:21.141  6596  6596 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(312)] "Error in Error callbackId: FacebookConnectPlugin304624227 : TypeError: r is not a function", source: http://localhost:12120/cordova.js (312)
I20161129-20:10:21.540(1)? 11-29 20:10:21.141  6596  6596 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(314)] "Uncaught TypeError: r is not a function", source: http://localhost:12120/cordova.js (314)
```

It works if I do `facebookConnectPlugin.login()` but it seems to crash whenever I add callbacks. Might be the cordova plugin version? I use 1.7.4.

Answer (score 0):

Some issue with the jsep:meteor-facebook-native-login I guess.

You have to specify permissions.

Example:

```
Meteor.loginWithNativeFacebook({
    requestPermissions: ['public_profile']
}, function(){
    // callback
});
```